# D3 Set labels on Legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend

I need help setting the labels on a D3 stacked bar chart. I'm not sure how to map the color in the legend with a reference to the name property in the data object.

I have a JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lhs3e7xk/1/

The code in particular I need help with is the legend function:

```
function updateLegend(dt) {
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain()) // I tried dt as well.
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
    });

    legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        console.log(d)
        return color(d.name)
      });
}
```

The output should be the value for the name property in the data set and the color associated with that group.

Fixed MBS    [Color01]
Floating MBS [Color02]
CMO          [Color03]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
  .text(function(d, i) {
    console.log(d)
    return color(d.name)
  })
```

do the text function like this:

```
  .text(function(d, i) {
    if(i==0)
     return "Fixed MBS"
     if(i==1)
     return "Floating MBS"
     if(i==2)
     return "CMO"

  });
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3L7y737n/)

**EDIT**

For setting legends using data
    //your dynamic legend data set
    var legends = ["Fixed MBS", "Floating MBS", "CMO"];

```
function updateLegend(dt) {
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(legends)//pass the lgend data
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
    });

    legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", function(d, i){return color(i)});//color based on index

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return d;//return the array data
      });
}
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3L7y737n/1/)

Comment: Thanks Cyril, this works but is there a way to dynamically set the labels? In reality, I could have may more than 3 sections and I'd also like to reuse this code for other charts so the labels may change. Maybe I can extract the labels into a different array but Ideally, the labels should be coming from the data-set. No?

Comment: check the edit section i have made it dynamic based on array